# validation code with <a> <noscript>

Tags: html, validation

I have a big problem with validation HTML 4.01

```
<li class="exampleclass">
    <noscript>
        <a href="http://www.skni.pl/index.html">  
    </noscript>

    <span id="showLoginboxButton" style="cursor: pointer;">Login</span>

    <noscript></a></noscript>

</li>
```

How can I fix it? I get such error

> end tag for element "A" which is not open
>
> …nboxButton" style="cursor:
>   pointer;">Login
>
> The Validator found an end tag for the above element, but that element
>   is not currently open. This is often caused by a leftover end tag from
>   an element that was removed during editing, or by an implicitly closed
>   element (if you have an error related to an element being used where
>   it is not allowed, this is almost certainly the case). In the latter
>   case this error will disappear as soon as you fix the original
>   problem.
>
> If this error occurred in a script section of your document, you
>   should probably read this FAQ entry.

Comment: What's with the `<noscript>` tags everywhere?

Comment: You can not open one element inside another, and then try to close it outside of it. Why don’t you just put the link in there anyways? If you don’t need it when JS is available, then suppress its default action.

Answer (score 4):

Notice how your code is organized:

```
<li class="exampleclass">
    <noscript>
        <a href="http://www.skni.pl/index.html">
    </noscript>
    <span id="showLoginboxButton" style="cursor: pointer;">Login</span>
    <noscript>
        </a>
    </noscript>
</li>
```

You are closing the `<noscript>` before closing the `<a>`.

You cannot do such interleaving of tags in HTML (or XML): **Every tag must be closed in the order that it was opened.** If a tag was opened inside another element, then it must be closed before the outer element can close. If this rule is not obeyed, a validation error will occur.

---

In order to achieve what you want, you can do something along the lines of:

```
<li class="exampleclass">
    <span id="showLoginboxButton" style="cursor: pointer; display: none">Login</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('showLoginboxButton').style.display = 'inline';
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <a href="http://www.skni.pl/index.html">Login</a>
    </noscript>
</li>
```

Basically you hide the `#showLoginboxButton` and show it only if there is JavaScript enabled.

Of course, as usual, try to avoid inline styling and script tags. I added them there just for example purposes, you should ultimately use a CSS class and that JavaScript code somewhere more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

@acdcjunior gave a good explanation of what happens in terms of HTML syntax and validity. On the practical side, the best approach is to avoid the `noscript` element (as suggested in HTML5 drafts) and apply the principle of unobtrusive JavaScript. In this case, you could write

```
<li class="exampleclass">
    <a href="http://www.skni.pl/index.html" id="showLoginboxButton">Login</a>
</li>
```

and do the rest in CSS and JavaScript. Your JavaScript would assign an `onclick` handler to the `a` element so that it does what a script has to do and eventually returns `false` or otherwise aborts normal link processing (if needed – I really can’t see how you could meaningfully do a login without server-side action.

Or maybe it should be a `button`. A login operation really calls for an action button rather than a link.